# Getting the indices of all non-None items from a sub-list in Python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

As per the title, I have a nested lists like so (the nested list is a fixed length):

```
        # ID,  Name, Value
list1 = [[ 1, "foo",    10],
         [ 2, "bar",  None],
         [ 3, "fizz",   57],
         [ 4, "buzz", None]]
```

I'd like to return a list (the number of items equal to the length of a sub-list from `list1`), where the sub-lists are the indices of rows without None as their Xth item, i.e.:

```
[[non-None ID indices], [non-None Name indices], [non-None Value indices]]
```

Using `list1` as an example, the result should be:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2]]
```

My current implementation is:

```
indices = [[] for _ in range(len(list1[0]))]
for i, row in enumerate(list1):
    for j in range(len(row)):
        if not isinstance(row[j], types.NoneType):
            indices[j].append(i)
```

...which works, but can be slow (the lengths of the lists are in the hundreds of thousands).

Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I've refactored the above for loops into nested list comprehensions (similar to SilentGhost's answer). The following line gives the same result as the my original implementation, but runs approximately 10x faster.

```
[[i for i in range(len(list1)) if list1[i][j] is not None] for j in range(len(log[0]))]
```

Comment: your edited variant is invalid due to `list1[i]` is always not `None` e.g., `list1[0]` is `[1, "foo", 10]` (note: `[None, None, None] is not None`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> [[i for i, j in enumerate(c) if j is not None] for c in zip(*list1)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2]]
```

in python-2.x you could use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` to avoid generating intermediate list.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[i for i in range(len(list1)) if list1[i] is not None] for _ in range(len(log[0]))]
```

The above seems to be about 10x faster than my original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

map(lambda a: np.not_equal(a, None).nonzero()[0], np.transpose(list1))
# -> [array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 2])]
```

Comment: this variant is 3 times slower than @SilentGhost's one (on some input).